# How do I set Firebase's 'Realtime Database' rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Simple question: Is there any problem with setting the 'read' and 'write' rule on my Realtime Database (Firebase) to 'true' (no authentication) if the user is **just reading** data from the database and **not writing** anything to it and there's no secret data stored in this database, that the user isn't supposed to see?

Answer (score 1):

If the user isn't writing anything at all, then I don't know why you would allow write access.  Just allow read access.  If you allow unconditional write access, then anyone with an internet connection will be able to write (and delete) that data.  If that's not what you want, then don't allow it.